# CPU time used last second

Tags: bash, cpu-usage

I'm programming in Bash and I'm trying to find out how much CPU time that were used in the last second. I also need to separate the systime (Kernel mode) and the usertime (User mode).

I've looked into **top** but I'm new at using UNIX/Terminal so I couldn't manage to get something out of there.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `vmstat(8)` utility. This often isn't installed on Linux systems by default, so if it's missing on your system you'll need to install it with out system's package manager.
In Fedora Core, it's part of the `sysstat` package.

Example output:

```
$ vmstat 1 2
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0    752 136480  31204 392176    0    0     2     1   40  101  0  0 99  0
 0  0    752 138268  31344 392416    0    0     0     0   59  205  0  1 99  0
```

The first line is the average since reboot, the second line is a sampling of the last second.

You want the cpu stats, obviously, the meaning of the columns are (from the manpage):

```
   CPU
       These are percentages of total CPU time.
       us: Time spent running non-kernel code.  (user time, including nice time)
       sy: Time spent running kernel code.  (system time)
       id: Time spent idle.  Prior to Linux 2.5.41, this includes IO-wait time.
       wa: Time spent waiting for IO.  Prior to Linux 2.5.41, included in idle.
       st: Time stolen from a virtual machine.  Prior to Linux 2.6.11, unknown.
```

You can use `awk(1)` to get the values, for example:

```
vmstat=$(vmstat 1 2 | tail -1)

# Kernel time
sys=$(echo "$vmstat" | awk '{print $14}')

# User time
sys=$(echo "$vmstat" | awk '{print $13}')
```

Related question: [How to get overall CPU Usage (e.g. 57%) on Linux [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux)

This should work on Linux, FreeBSD, and probably MacOSX.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. That helped a lot! The vmstat utility was installed on my Ubuntu 13.10 :)